# Replenishing a sender with credits

Tags: java, eclipse-hono

I am trying to implement a Hono sender that sends a large amount of data to a Hono instance however I keep running into an issue with the sender running out of credits. Specifically. "cannot send message while waiting for replenishment with credit". How can I trigger the sender to be replenished with credits or wait for more credits to be available before sending the next message?

Comment: Hi, can you update the question with the code. especially, the part where you take care of queue drain handler?

Comment: Hi kucing_terbang. At the moment there is know queue drain handler. I was following along to the example under the 0.7 branch and have not seen that implemted. How would you advice I handle this?

Comment: Hi kucing_terbang. At the moment there is know queue drain handler. I was following along to the example under the 0.7 branch and have not seen that implemted. How would you advice I handle this?

Comment: I see, could you try to trigger the request again? But, try to wait a while before you trigger it. As, probably, the HTTP adapter may not receive credits quickly enough for the request to be served immediately. If it is still happen, I would try it in my local later.

Comment: I have added the following code and it still does not appear to work, any help would be appreciated.
https://pastebin.com/mZScyiVk
@kucing_terbang

Answer (score 0):

One reason for this may the fact that you do not have a consumer running when sending telemetry data. Hono does handle back-pressure by waiting for a consumer to be capable of receiving messages. However, if there is no consumer currently running, then then your sender will not receive credits as well.

Also see: https://www.eclipse.org/hono/deployment/openshift/#uploading-telemetry-with-http